# Checking to see if cell values are integers, if not then adding message

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column (col G) where I want to verify the values are numeric. If they are not numeric I want to paste an error message in col A. I don't get any errors when running my code, but it seems to print the error message even though there is a number in the cell.

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

For Each cell In Range("G2:" & "G" & lastRow)
If IsNumeric(Range("G2:" & "G" & lastRow)) = True Then cell.Offset(0, -6).Value = cell.Offset(0, -6).Value & ", G is not a number"
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looping through cells with condition could be done like this:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Worksheets(1).Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cell In Worksheets(1).Range("G2:" & "G" & lastRow)
        If IsError(cell) Then
            cell.Offset(0, -6).Value = cell.Address & " is error!"
        ElseIf Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
            cell.Offset(0, -6).Value = cell.Value & " is not a number"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

It is a good practice to refer to the parent worksheet as in `Worksheets(1).Range...`.

Comment: @Vityata, excellent answer. However, would you want to add a check for cell value in error. Something like this before the test `IsNumeric`: `If VarType(cell.Value) = vbError Then
        cell.offset(0, -6).Value = "Cell is in error"
    Else`

Comment: @Guest - thanks :) I have added the `IsError()` part.